# BigQuery job intermittent failure with jobInternalError

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer

We are experiencing a strange issue with Cloud Composer BigQueryOperator tasks (in multiple DAGs) and some scheduled queries. It happens randomly and intermittently and on retrying, the same jobs/queries execute successfully.

Looking into the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT:

```
error_result.reason = jobInternalError<br>
error_result.message = The job encountered an internal error during execution and was unable to complete successfully.
```

But there are bytes billed etc. and the child jobs appear to be successful.

This started happening only since yesterday and we have not made any changes to any of these jobs.

Wondering if others have experienced this recently as well. How do we debug this further or get additional assistance on this?

An example error message received from a cloud Composer Task failure:

```
Exception:
BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {'reason': 'jobInternalError', 'message': 'The job encountered an internal error during execution and was unable to complete successfully.'}. The job was: {'kind': 'bigquery#job', 'etag': 'cFex61A/InyX/L1+vy8GHw==', 'id': '#################:US.job_FIr-PFixKsdVvOJddG9zuIUeSj1i', 'selfLink': 'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/#################/jobs/job_FIr-PFixKsdVvOJddG9zuIUeSj1i?location=US', 'user_email': '###########@developer.gserviceaccount.com', 'configuration': {'query': {'query': '############################################;\n ', 'priority': 'INTERACTIVE', 'useLegacySql': False}, 'jobType': 'QUERY'}, 'jobReference': {'projectId': '#################', 'jobId': 'job_FIr-PFixKsdVvOJddG9zuIUeSj1i', 'location': 'US'}, 'statistics': {'creationTime': '1629364585265', 'startTime': '1629364585352', 'endTime': '1629365366433', 'totalBytesProcessed': '135043690', 'query': {'totalBytesProcessed': '135043690', 'totalBytesBilled': '492830720', 'totalSlotMs': '192771', 'schema': {'fields': [{'name': 'total_rows', 'type': 'NUMERIC', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}]}, 'statementType': 'SCRIPT'}, 'totalSlotMs': '192771', 'numChildJobs': '69'}, 'status': {'errorResult': {'reason': 'jobInternalError', 'message': 'The job encountered an internal error during execution and was unable to complete successfully.'}, 'state': 'DONE'}}
Log: Link
Host: airflow-worker-##############
Log file: /home/airflow/gcs/logs/#########################/bq_build_reconciliation/2021-08-18T09:00:00+00:00.log
Mark success: Link
```

An example failure message from a scheduled query:

```
2021-08-19T03:06:13.536907177Z
Job scheduled_query_6148e950-0000-2b6a-89c9-94eb2c09dfdc (table ) failed with error INTERNAL: The job encountered an internal error during execution and was unable to complete successfully.; JobID: ##########:scheduled_query_6148e950-0000-2b6a-89c9-94eb2c09dfdc
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is it still happening? I heard there was some temporary issue just before the weekend, but it was solved already. If you still face some you can raise a bug via [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/getting-support#issuetracker)

Comment: It appears to be resolved, thanks for the info!